# Ping failed, unknown system variable 'language'

Tags: java, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to connect Eclipse to phpMyAdmin but when I'm trying to do a Test Connection I get this error:

```
Ping failed! java.sql.SQLException: Unknown system variable 'language'
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:965)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3973)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3909)...
```

I am working with [mysql-connector-java-5.1.38](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.38). I have tried other versions but with the same result.
I access phpMyAdmin with WampServer.

Any ideas for me? Thank you.

Comment: You cannot connect eclipse to phpmyadmin. Java is not PHP. phpmyadmin is a php frontend for administering mysql.

Comment: I'm trying to connect eclipse to a database that i created in phpmyadmin

Comment: @PaulBotezatu please provide connection URL which you use in Java to connect. For MySQL it should look like this `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/data`

Comment: @Ivan,this is the url  `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/studentiac`

Comment: @PaulBotezatu, please check this link https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=77665. Maybe you have to use newer version of MySQL database or downgrade MySQL JDBC driver

Comment: @Ivan, thank you very much. I used   mysql-connector-java-5.1.0   with MySQL JDBC version 4.0 ( I found a table that showed me the compatibility).  Still, what is very strange to me is that a friend of mine used mysql-connector-java-5.1.38 and MySQL JDBC version 5.1 and that worked for him and for me don't. This thing I can't explain to myself